# Sharepoint share link still available after expiration date

Tags: file, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, share, sharepoint-online

Following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

I wanted create share link with expirationDateTime. I also wanted use scope as user and grant permission for this link to selected users in organization. Unfortunately when link expired this users still have access to it. Is there anyone who tried do something like this? Or is any way to give user one-time link to sharepoint file?

Comment: I know, but it's not solving my problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Check the remarks, looks like your case:

> Links created using this action do not expire unless a default
> expiration policy is enforced for the organization.

Resource:

[Share a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#remarks)