# Azure Graph API - Setting expiration timestamp for sharable link

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

As per [Azure Graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), request format for sharing a SharePoint document with an expirable link is below format. But it is not working as link is accessible even after the configured time.

```
{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "email": "ryan@contoso.com"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.",
  "requireSignIn": true,
  "sendInvitation": true,
  "roles": [ "write" ],
  "password": "password123",
  "expirationDateTime": "2023-10-12T14:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I've already went through below post, but this is a different API.
[SharePoint share link still available after expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461527/sharepoint-share-link-still-available-after-expiration-date)

Comment: According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/477533/unable-send-a-file-sharing-invitation-via-graph-ap) and [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1535) expirationDateTime has no effect

Comment: I agree with @user2250152 when you provide `expirationDateTime` in request body, it is not returning in **API response value** like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Ex4iwxv.png) that confirms `expirationDateTime` has no effect on SharePoint share link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I agree with @user2250152  `expirationDateTime` has no effect on SharePoint share link.

When I ran below request to send sharing invitation, I got **response** without `expirationDateTime` in it:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/invite

{
    "recipients": [
        {
            "email": "sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.",
    "requireSignIn": true,
    "sendInvitation": true,
    "roles": [
        "write"
    ],
    "password": "password123",
    "expirationDateTime": "2023-10-13T05:59:11.716Z"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

This automatically sends mail with **shared file link** to recipient's email address like this:

[image]

When user clicks that **shared link** even after expiration time, it is accessible as below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can run below request to **delete** the permission on shared link after some time:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/permissions/{permissionId}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When user tries to access the shared link again now, it will throw **Access Denied** error as below:

[image]